# Frontend and communication for EC2 based cloud application

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud

We are implementing a system that will take some image as input, do some processing on it, and return the results. We have to do the processing on an EC2 instance. I'm pretty new to cloud computing in general, and haven't worked with the web either, and I'm trying to decide the best way to create the frontend for this system. (The backend is simply c++ code running on amazon EC2). For the frontend, I have two options:

- A desktop app that will somehow communicate with the EC2 instance. This one is simpler to build, as I've some experience with this, but I don't know how I will be able to talk to the backend. There's SSH, but I don't know how suitable it is.
- A webserver running on the EC2 instance itself. This sounds like a better idea , but I haven't done any webdevelopment, so might end up taking more time.

I'm not looking to create any fancy UIs, just something functional that lets the end user upload the image, and view the results. Which option should I go for?

Answer (score 0):

There are pros and cons of both approaches, but given your brief description and the simplicity of the application a web based approach would seem a good match.

This gives some advantages:

- easy to deploy (nothing to install on users machines)
- easy to upgrade (again no impact on users machines)
- with some basic good practice (sticking to standards and using 'responsive web design' for example) it should run on most browsers and most machines without modification

Some common limitations to be aware of:

- If your target is mobile, users may prefer an 'app' experience than browser based experience
- if you have any strict real time or performance requirements, then sometimes native applications may perform better (it depends on the actual requirements)